# How to prove that a logarithmic integral is transcendental?

Tags: reference-request, logarithms, transcendence-theory, transcendental-functions

After I've read, from [1], a proof that the logarithm $\log (x)$, defined for $x>0$, is a trancendental function, I wondered what should be the argument to prove (I believe that it holds) that the logarithmic integral is a trancendental function.

I mean the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{li}(x)$ as the function defined for $x\neq 1$ as the function defined for example from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html), or well as $$\operatorname{Li}(x):=\int_a^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$$ for some $a>1$ that you need.

> **Question.** Can you provide me hints or an explanation about how is it proven  in mathematics that a logarithmic integral is a transcendental function? That is, what is the reasoning to prove that a logarithmic integral is transcendental? **Many thanks.**

If the method is very difficult or little know feel, or do you need to invoke theorems free to refer the literature and I try to find and read it.

### References:

[1] R. Rouse, *The natural logarithm is transcendental*, Classroom Notes, p. 187-188 of the American Mathematical Monthly (February, 1966).

Comment: According to Liuville theorem, $\operatorname{Li}(x):=\int_a^x\dfrac{dt}{\log t}$ is elementary if there exists a rational function $p$ such that $\operatorname{Li}(x)=p(x)e^x$, so you need some calculations to find a contradiction with it!

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @MyGlasses